# Weird function call in java addData( a, b {some crap})

Tags: java

I encountered a weird function call which is shown below:

```
addData("abc", "abc" {
        public boolean isDataCorrect() {
          return true;
        }
      });
```

addData signature is

```
public void addData(String a, String b);
```

Can anyone explain whats the code in curly braces doing? Moreover how is it even working?

Comment: Why post code that doesn't compile? That is disrespectful of the participants here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That doesn't compile.

Probably you're seeing which does not longer exists.

For instance suppose that the `addData` method use to receive `String a , OtherClass b` Later on, the OtherClass was substituted by String and in  an automatic re-factoring, that came, something like:

```
// BEFORE
addData( "abc", new AbcValidator("abc"){  
       public boolan isDataCorrect(){
          return true;
       }
});  
addData( String a, AbcValidator b ) {
}
```

After refactoring, someone ( probably a bad refactoring tool ) thought the raw string could be used.

```
// AFTER:
addData( "abc", "abc"{  
       public boolan isDataCorrect(){
          return true;
       }
});  
addData( String a, AbcValidator b ) {
}
```

When you compile it and run it, it doesn't even compile, but since it was running before, the run script takes the previous version ( the one using AbcValidator )  and looks like it is working, but it is not.

It is almost impossible to guess what is happening in your desk, but make no mistakes, that doesn't run.

To probe it do the following:

A) create a new directory and a java "Hey.java" with the following contents:

```
class Hey{
    public static void main( String [] args ) {
        addData("abc",   "abc" {
            public boolean isDataCorrect() {
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
    public void addData( String a, String b ){}
}
```

B) Compile that file, preferably from the command line: `javac Hey.java`

You'll see it doesn't works.

Comment: Yes you are right. But can you further explain one thing. The code under comment "//Before" where addData expects an object as its second parameter, what is the code inside {} doing. I mean u just need an object, so you can call a constructor. Why do you need that extra lines of code.

Comment: He's extending the AbcValidator interface (not shown). I've posted a (slightly) more extended version of that below.

Comment: That's an anonymous inner class. It is commonly used to create an inline subclass of another class. That's what Java invented years ago in substitution for closures, they are actually closures, but very verbose.  They are very handy to provide new class implementations.

Comment: Seems like poor  refraction in action with of an anonymous class.anonmyous classes are generally used to provide online definitions of interfaces or extending behaviuir of existing classes with minimal addition to the class behaviour. Refraction made it look something else.

Answer (score 1):

Your example doesn't compile. The closest thing I know of that you can do like that is an initialization block, like

```
public void addData(Map ... )
addData(new HashMap(){ { put("A", "B");}}
```

or an anonymous class declared when the function is called:

```
public interface Adder { public boolean isDataCorrect(); }
public void addData(Adder ...)
addData(new Adder(){ public boolean isDataCorrect();}...
```

You can't do anything like this with strings, like implement an interface or add a method to a subclass, because the String class is final.